# On differentiable functions on real line satisfying $f'(x)\ge f(x)^2 , \forall x>0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, uniform-continuity, lipschitz-functions

Does there exist a real valued differentiable function $f$ on real line such that $f'(x) \ge f(x)^2 , \forall x >0$ ? If such a function exist , must it be twice differentiable or at least Lipschitz ?  Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: yes, the zero function

Comment: The zero function is one solution. ANother is $x\mapsto -e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 2):

If you restrict to equality, you have
$$
\frac{du}{dt} = u^2,
$$
which separates to
$$
u^{-2}du = dt
$$
and integration yields
$$
\frac{-1}{u} = t+C
$$
so
$$
u = \frac{-1}{t+C}
$$
should do.

Comment: It depends. If the OP wants a function that is defined on the _whole number line_ then you need to tweak this slightly.

Comment: @Arthur indeed, at $t = -C$ we have issues. But he only needs for $t >0$ so any $C < 0$ will do, and we have an entire class of functions that satisfy that condition.

Comment: And for a function that is not twice differentiable we can splice something like $$ f(x)=\begin{cases}\text{whatever} & x<0 \\ -1/(x+\tfrac12) & 0\le x < 1/2 \\ -\exp(\tfrac12-x) & x \ge 1/2 \end{cases} $$

Comment: He wants the _condition_ to hold for positive inputs, but he possibly wants the function $f$ to be differentiable everywhere. Anyways, it's only a small matter of having some piecewise definition that is differentiable and equals $-\frac1{x+c}$ for positive $x$. Or, $\frac{-1}{x+c}$ might be good enough on its own. It's hard to tell.